# Two parts that share a common footprint - a connector, two two pin connectors that share a four pad footprint but are never populated at the same time

Tags: altium

The manufacturer GCT of a two pin connector [BG306-02-A-1-0400-L-G](https://www.digikey.com/short/m90z0f0m) offers two different versions. One version has the pads in the upper right and lower left. The other, you guessed it, has the pads in the upper left and lower right. Both connectors will work for my application. I'd like to make a 4 pad footprint and populate either one part or the other but never both so when I can't get one I can use to other. I can't figure out how to configure the schematic part(s) and the layout such that the schematic has two part on it and each one can be populated or not. And a PCB footprint that has pads for both parts, all four pads

Comment: Why not just make one footprint that covers both cases?

Comment: The footprint will be common but the orientation of the contacts will be different.

!(https://imgur.com/ArDrB2L)

Comment: But why can't you have a footprint with four pads?

Comment: The footprint will be common but the orientation of the contacts will be different between the two different parts. Variants is the way to go. But, Altium seems to have a problem with variants that have different 3D models for the part. It can do one or the other but not both. The variant 3D model comes up blank. It could be me that is doing something wrong of course but I numerous combinations of trying alternate libraries and copying and renaming parts. Every time I would think, ah this is it and the problem would resurface but as a missing 3D model on the other variant. The BOMs are good

Comment: Do you *need* a 3d model of the part?

Comment: The foot print has four pads but the connector has two. It works well with variants but the missing 3D model on the variant is kind of a buzz kill. The BOM comes out good but the 3D model is missing the parts. Not a show stopper but it's awesome when everything looks good. I don't need a 3D model but it looks better if it did. The problem is the differing 3D models between the two variants don't show up when you click between the variants. Whatever part is selected as the primary becomes the one that shows up. The different 3D model for the variant comes up blank, even though both have models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this situation for me was to include a note on the assembly drawing. The note details the fact that although the part as only two pads, the footprint has the provisions for either variant.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> *I can't figure out how to configure the schematic part(s) and the
> layout such that the schematic has two part on it and each one can be
> populated or not.*

**Footprint: -**

[image]

Image from [this drawing](https://gct.co/files/drawings/bg306.pdf).

**Part in schematic**

Make it have twice as many pins as a single part and connect up the pins appropriately. Or do something like this: -

[image]

**Alternatively: -**

Just draw the schematic with both connectors and, when it comes to the layout, drop them on top of each other and disable the errors that the PCB editor displays.

Comment: HI Andy - Thank you for the response. I'm going to try to do it with two different variants. I think that will solve my issue. One variant will be the -1 option and the other will be the -2 option. The footprints will be the same for both, a four pad foot print for a 2 pin part. My question had more to do with how to manage two parts that reside on the same foot print. And when I asked the question like this, I realized that a variant was the way to go

Comment: @ignoramusextraordinaire you should also take the [2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why people give their free time to help people in need. I'm mentioning this because although you've been a member for three years, you don't appear to have formally accepted any answers yet and, despite having sufficient reputation, you don't appear to have upvoted single answers. It's the site etiquette if you want a name for it.

Comment: I will, sorry to burn up your time.

Comment: It's not a problem if you do the right thing then, it certainly won't be a problem

Answer (score -1):

Variants is the way to do this. The part has two connections and there are two different variations from the manufacturer. One that has the connections on the upper right and lower left, the other has the connections on the upper left and lower right. The foot print would have four pads to accommodate the two parts with differing connection layouts. This works for BOM generation. Altium (or this user) seems to have trouble with variants that don't share a common 3D model. I have tried numerous ways to over come the issue or realize what I was doing wrong but nothing I did allowed me to have different 3D models between the two variants. Whichever part was the original would have it's 3D model used. The other 3D model on the variant appears on the 3D to be missing. This is no trouble for the BOM but the CM I use looks at the 3D pdf and they'll say 'the part is missing on the 3D model, should we proceed" Or if I use the same 3D model, they'll say "the connectors on the 3D on this variant don't match the datasheet, should proceed' they don't miss a beat